# Black screen with blinking underscore in Lubuntu guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, lubuntu

I installed VirtualBox and downloaded the Lubuntu 18.04 image. Then I created a new virtual machine with VirtualBox. I did everything like in TechGumbo´s How to Use VirtualBox (Beginners Guide) video.

If I start the virtual machine I get to a menu where I can select *Try Lubuntu without installing*, *Install Lubuntu*, *Test memory*, ... But If I select try or install Lubuntu I get a black screen with a blinking underscore.

I read that selecting nomodeset would solve the problem, but it did not solve the problem in my case.

I also tried to use different version of Lubuntu or Ubuntu (Ubuntu only older versions which support 32-bit), but it did not help.

My environment:

OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
  System name: LAPTOP-020N45Q6
  System model: HP 250 G5 Notebook PC
  System type: 64-bit PC
  System SKU: X0Q92EA#ABD
  Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz, 2901 MHz, 2 cores, 4 logical processors
  BIOS Version/-date: Insyde F.21, 27.10.2016
  SMBIOS Version: 2.8
  BIOS Mode: UEFI
  C:\WINDOWS\system32
  RAM 8:00 GB